# FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly Syncfusion.sfpopuplayout.XForms

Tags: xamarin.forms, nuget, syncfusion

I'm not sure how to resolve this. During runtime, I'm getting an initialization error

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Syncfusion.SfPopupLayout.XForms, Version=18.4451.0.33, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

The file (if this is the correct one) exists here:

```
C:\Users....nuget\packages\syncfusion.xamarin.sfpopuplayout\18.4.0.33\lib\netstandard2.0\Syncfusion.SfPopupLayout.XForms.dll
```

This is happening in the constructor of my ContentPage.

The Dependencies/Packages folder shows Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPopupLayout(18.4.0.33). I see the error is reporting 18.4451.0.33. Is that a significant difference ? What do I do ?

Thanks.

EDIT: I have installed the latest version of this package, using nuget.

Answer (score 0):

Install the `Syncfusion.Xamarin.SfPopupLayout` from NuGet.

[image]

After that, you could use this control.

Xaml:

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:sfPopup="clr-namespace:Syncfusion.XForms.PopupLayout;assembly=Syncfusion.SfPopupLayout.XForms"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Class="Test.MainPage">

<sfPopup:SfPopupLayout x:Name="popupLayout">
    <sfPopup:SfPopupLayout.Content>
        <StackLayout x:Name="mainLayout">
            <Button x:Name="clickToShowPopup" Text="ClickToShowPopup" 
           VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
            Clicked="ClickToShowPopup_Clicked"/>
        </StackLayout>
    </sfPopup:SfPopupLayout.Content>
</sfPopup:SfPopupLayout>  

</ContentPage>
```

Comment: I should have been more explicit. The package is installed and I verified the file is present. The problem is there is (or VS thinks there is) a reference to a newer version. But no such newer version is available.

Comment: Have you checked the package in installed of NuGet? If it was there, delete the bin and obj folder to clean and rebuild. If you still get this error, create a new project to install the package to test.

Comment: Yes, in my OP I show the file and path. In fact, yesterday I completely uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio, plus deleted the object files for my project.

Comment: Could you provide your Xamarin.forms version? Or could you upload a code sample with could reproduce on GitHub?

Answer (score 0):

I have prepared sample and checked the SfPopupLayout in the mentioned NuGet version of 18.4.0.33 and it is working fine. Attached tested sample in the in the following link

sample [link]: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/PopupLayout112920991

Please check shared project and revert us if the reported issue is occurring in this sample too, if not check your project file maybe you installed more than one version of SfPopupLayout package.

Regards,
Pradeep Kumar B

Comment: I will, but it probably won't be till saturday. Thanks.